# Spring Security 3 - permitAll() not working

Tags: spring, security

that is my  test configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtService jwtService;

   @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthFilter(jwtService), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();

    }

}
```

i sent a request by Postman on "localhost:8085/api/auth/login" but jwtAuthFilter was triggered.
during debugging this class on "return http.build()" I noticed that field RequestMatcherConfigurer has empty matchers field.
I do not use any AuthenticationProvider, beceause its an API gateway and i dont event have a database.
What is wrong with that code?** it does not work even when I set** **anyRequest().permitAll()**

Spring: 3.1.1
Security: 6.1

Comment: Not wanting to apply a jwt filter for a particular api?

Answer (score 0):

OncePerRequestFilter has [shouldNotFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html#shouldNotFilter(jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)) method to avoid filtering for some requests